# Ler um JSON a partir de uma URL

Tags: c#, json, mobile, windows-phone

Preciso ler um arquivo JSON, que é gerado pelo `PHP`, através do `json_encode`;

Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, vocês tem algum exemplo?

**Observação:**

É em **Windows Phone 8 C#!**

A resposta que a url dá é a seguinte:

`{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"0","churros":"0","2":"0","crepes":"0","3":"1","aberto":"1","4":"0","pulapula":"0"}`

> Url: http://webradioelectro.comxa.com/informacoes.php

Comment: Você quer fazer isso por javascript ou php?

Se for por js você pode usar a função da jQuery chamada $.getJSON();

Doc: https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.getjson%2F&ei=fR5YU9ycNYet2QXk0oEY&usg=AFQjCNEB9qOPBeSVZLiVcekqkCXbTffRMA&sig2=0VSgsOL9A-iSrVW8MBphgA&bvm=bv.65177938,d.b2I

Ele retorna para você um objeto js.

Comment: @RandsonJarthis Quero fazer em windows phone 8. Ta na tag (:

Comment: Essa página não retorna um `application/json` .

Comment: @Beterraba em android eu consegui fazer...

Comment: @Bacco em Windows Phone 8 C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução:**

*Baixe o Pacote* [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.2), vai ser de grande utilidade para solução do problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Struct:**

*Crie uma struct igual a essa:*

```
public struct LayoutJson
{        
    public LayoutJson(String Index, String Value)           
    {
        _index = Index;
        _value = Value;
    }
    private string _index;    
    public string Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set { _index = value; }
    }
    private string _value;    
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set { this._value = value; }
    }
}
```

---

**Rotina de Leitura e Padronização desse Json**

```
//Lista de Valores
IList<LayoutJson> ResultJson;

//Metodo que é responsável por conectar na url e baixar o conteudo
public void GetJsonUrl()
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    web.DownloadStringCompleted += web_DownloadStringCompleted;
    web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://webradioelectro.comxa.com/informacoes.php", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));            
}
void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        string[] results = e.Result.Split(new string[1] { "<!--" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (results.Count() > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable objetoJson = (IEnumerable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results[0]);
            ResultJson = new List<LayoutJson>();
            foreach (var item in objetoJson)
            {
                string[] values = null;
                if (DescribeKeyValue(item, ref values))
                {
                    ResultJson.Add(new LayoutJson(values[0], values[1]));
                }                        
            }                    
        }
    }
}
//Descobre o Valor de cada item
bool DescribeKeyValue(object item, ref string[] values)
{
    try
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            values = item.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split(':');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Observações:**

Perceba que na rotina foi utilizado um `Split` no retorno do contéudo do site, porque ele veio dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, foi divida a `string` para pegar somente o `Json`.

Outro fator importante dizer que esse Json não segue padrão, por isso criado uma `struct` para guarda cada posição do mesmo, se tivesse um padrão daria para fazer um `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`, onde `T` seria um `class` ou `struct`

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi obtido 10 itens com Index e Value, agora é só trabalhar na programação assim:

```
foreach (LayoutJson item in ResultJson)
{
       //item.Index
       //item.Value
}
```

ou, como preferir

Comment: Está dando erro, dizendo que a lista está vazia. Quando eu tento chamar ela no main, a lista volta vazia ou null

Comment: Depende se você segui passo a passo, deve ta faltando alguma coisa, poste o seu código no `pastebin.com` que eu olho.